# Sitemap Plugin for WordPress Network

Tags: multisite

Is there a plugin similar to the [Google Sitemap](http://www.arnebrachhold.de/projects/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-generator/) plugin that works for a mutli-site install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [Google XML Sitemaps with Multisite support](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-with-multisite-support/).

You can also use the development version of the original [Google XML Sitemaps](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-google-xml-sitemaps-early-testers-wanted/page/2#post-1721335). It seems to be working fine for some people.